# Record count dropping after Union-all in SSIS

Tags: ssis, union-all

I have three inputs to the union. I've mapped columns from each input to their respective column. Column [T-end] is a datetime column present in two inputs. The moment I configure both the inputs to the output column, the record count drops by 10,000 records. If i ignore one of the input columns, the count is fine.

I have already confirmed that the Data type of both the columns are of the same datatype.

Comment: The information you have provided is incomplete. Please share information of your input and output columns, variables and screen shot of your data flow task.

Comment: It seems that rather you need to use the Data Flow's *Multicast* component